How to fill a Path in a Canvas using a Material style
A Canvas receives a GraphicsContext as closure parameter and this can be used to draw and fill shapes.
If a path is filled with a Material style, it just fills with (almost) solid black, instead of the usual translucent effect:
struct ContentView: View {
    let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Color.clear
                Color.orange
            }
            Text(loremIpsum)
                .font(.title2)
                .padding()
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                .padding(.bottom, 160)
            Canvas { ctx, size in
                let path = Path(
                    roundedRect: CGRect(
                        x: (size.width - 200) / 2,
                        y: (size.height - 100) / 2 ,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 100
                    ),
                    cornerRadius: 10
                )
                ctx.fill(path, with: .style(.ultraThinMaterial))
            }
            .padding(.top, 160)
        }
    }
}


I tried using a .palette too, but then the Material effect is ignored (there is no blurring):
ctx.fill(path, with: .palette([
    .color(white: 0, opacity: 0.2),
    .style(.ultraThinMaterial)
]))


How can a GraphicsContext be used to fill a Path with a Material style to give the usual translucent effect?

The canvas uses a different graphics context from the text and colour views underneath it, so it doesn't "know" that the text and colours exist. As far as the canvas is concerned, the background is pitch black. Set Canvas(opaque: true) to see this in action.
You can draw the views in the same graphics context by using the draw overload that takes a ResolvedSymbol.
Canvas { ctx, size in
    let symbol = ctx.resolveSymbol(id: "my view")!
    ctx.draw(symbol, in: .init(origin: .zero, size: size))
    let path = Path(
        roundedRect: CGRect(
            x: (size.width - 200) / 2,
            y: (size.height - 100) / 2 ,
            width: 200,
            height: 100
        ),
        cornerRadius: 10
    )
    ctx.fill(path, with: .style(.ultraThinMaterial))
} symbols: {
    ZStack {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.white
            Color.orange
        }
        Text(loremIpsum)
            .font(.title2)
            .padding()
    }
    .tag("my view")
}

Notice that I changed Color.clear in the HStack to Color.white. This is because as I mentioned before, the "background" of the context is pitch black, so Color.clear would have created a black left half.
The output doesn't look exactly like the Rectangle().fill(.ultraThinMaterial), possibly because some settings of the graphics context of the canvas is a bit different from that of the graphic context used to draw the Rectangle.

But at least you can tell it's a material. :D

This is a helpful workaround and it certainly looks like a Material, thank you! So the effect does work, but the content that is seen behind the Material needs to be brought into the Canvas. This rather restricts what can be shown, don't think a ScrollView works, for example. Also interesting that setting opaque: true only makes part of the area black, not the full Canvas frame. Some optimisations at work, perhaps.

I found a couple of workarounds.
1. Apply the shape as a mask
The path is filled with an opaque color. This filled shape is then applied as a .mask to a base layer that is filled with the material effect:
Rectangle()
    .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
    .mask {
        Canvas { ctx, size in
            let path = Path(
                // as before
            )
            ctx.fill(path, with: .foreground)
        }
    }
    .padding(.top, 160)

2. Use blendMode to cut out the filled shape
The idea is to apply the Material effect in the background of the Canvas, then to cut away all parts of the background that shouldn't have the effect.
The process is:

invert the path, by subtracting it from a full-area rectangle
fill the inverted path with a solid color (such as the foreground color)
combine with the background using .blendMode(.destinationOut)
finally, add .compositingGroup(), to prevent the blend mode from going deeper than the canvas background.

Canvas { ctx, size in
    let path = Path(
        // as before
    )
    let inversePath = Path(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)).subtracting(path)
    ctx.fill(inversePath, with: .foreground)
}
.blendMode(.destinationOut)
.background(.ultraThinMaterial)
.compositingGroup()
.frame(height: 400) // to keep it away from the safe area edges
.padding(.top, 160) // as before

The result is the same in both cases:


What role does the Canvas actually play here? This seems like a very convoluted way of filling an arbitrary path with a material. Couldn't you have just made a custom Shape and filled that with a material?

@Sweeper In this case yes, a simple Shape can be used (as already being shown for comparison). The question is a simplified example for the purpose of demonstrating the issue. But there will be cases where a Canvas will be needed and where you would like to use a Material to fill a shape. My answer to How to add rounded borders that cling to a Text in SwiftUI is one such case.

@Sweeper I created a new post to explore this further

I see. That is a good point. When I saw that question by rayaantaneja I immediately thought about using TextKit :D
